# How to calculate PSNR metric in KERAS

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to calculate PSNR metric for my keras autoencoder convnet model. however, i run into an error. please help to check and rectify the issue. Thanks

```
import math
from keras import backend as K


def PSNR(y_true, y_pred):
    max_pixel = 1.0
    return 10.0 * math.log10((max_pixel ** 2) / (K.mean(K.square(y_pred - 
y_true)))) 


adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
autoencoder.compile(loss='mse', metrics=[PSNR], optimizer=adam)
```

The complete traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    autoencoder.compile(loss='mse', metrics=[PSNR], optimizer=adm)

File "C:\Users\LW\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_demo\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 451, in compile
    handle_metrics(output_metrics)

File "C:\Users\LW\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_demo\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 420, in handle_metrics
    mask=masks[i])

File "C:\Users\LW\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_demo\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 404, in weighted
    score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)

File "", line 8, in PSNR
    return 10.0 * math.log10((max_pixel ** 2) / (K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true))))

TypeError: must be real number, not Tensorr

please let me know how to resolve this

Comment: error is not coming from PSNR check http://tpcg.io/vebk7D. what is the complete error? btw log(1) base 10 is always 0

Comment: Yes, please add complete traceback.

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro please check the traceback Thanks

Comment: @abdul qayyum thanks, can you suggest something

Comment: try to print data, what is the shape of your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, Matias Valdenegro's answer didn't work well. I spent almost a day to find out what's wrong with my model, but finally I found the function Valdenegro wrote is wrong.

Here's what I modified.
First, do not multiply 2.303. Instead, divide. Because natural log is bigger than base-10 log.
Second, according to [keras api](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py), there should be a 'axis=-1' parameter in K.mean to calculate mse.
So, function looks like

```
def PSNR(y_true, y_pred):
    max_pixel = 1.0
    return (10.0 * K.log((max_pixel ** 2) / (K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)))) / 2.303
```

Comment: sometimes psnr can be inf, maybe y_pred == y_true. It's not a big problem (for me), but if you don't want to see it, just square (y_pred - y_true + 1e-8)

Comment: There is a function named `tf.image.psnr` in Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.image.psnr` from tensorflow.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/psnr
just change the `max_val` depends on your needs.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use `math.log` inside a keras metric or loss function, since it does not operate on symbolic tensors. Use `(1.0 / math.log(10)) * K.log` instead. The conversion factor is applied since `K.log` is the natural logarithm, and you want base-10 logarithm.

```
import math
def PSNR(y_true, y_pred):
    max_pixel = 1.0
    return 10.0 * (1.0 / math.log(10)) * K.log((max_pixel ** 2) / (K.mean(K.square(y_pred - 
y_true))))
```

Comment: why am i getting a high PSNR around 77 , you think it is correct. All my images are normalized between 1 and  0.